# из списка в число

Tags: python

как сделать так чтобы из списка получилось число,например есть список [1,2,3,4,5],надо получить число 12345

Comment: Берите перебором первый элемент списка, умножайте на 10 сохраняйте куда нибудь. Далее берите следующий и суммируйте с предыдущим результатом, снова умножайте на 10..... и так до конца списка.

Answer (score 1):

Разбивайте задачи на части, решайте или гуглите их по-отдельности, это же главный навык ИТшника!

1. Объединять числа напрямую слишком сложно? Зато строки легко! Значит, переводим список чисел в список строк применяя функцию `str` ко всем элементам списка: `map(str, data)` или `[str(x) for x in data]`
2. Надо объединить все строки в списке? Для этого есть метод `str.join` (или можно проще, через цикл).
3. Что дальше? Числа переведены в строки, склеены, получилась целая строка... А нужно число! Применяем функцию `int`.

Итого, осталось объединить всё в итоговое решение:

```py
data = [3, 14, 15]

result = int(''.join(map(str, data)))
```

Comment: Да конечно же можно объединять числа напрямую!

Comment: @Эникейщик конечно можно суммировать через цикл, но тогда надо учитывать количество цифр в числах. Через строки, думаю, новичку будет проще. Хотя можно добавить как второй вариант, более пригодный для языков вроде Си; чуть позже запишу.

Answer (score 0):

Без использования строк:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
result = 0
for num in numbers:
    result = result * 10 + num

print(result)
```

Работает только для однозначных чисел. Чтобы работало и для всех остальных чисел, немного усложним и применим десятичный интригал(c), т.е. логарифм:

```
import math
numbers = [11,22,33,444,555]
result = 0
for num in numbers:
    power = math.ceil(math.log10(num))
    result = result * 10**power + num

print(result)
```

Comment: Но годится только для чисел из одной цифры ;

Comment: Ага, добавил. Щас расширю для остальных тоже ;)

Comment: result = sum(d * 10**i for i, d in enumerate(list[::-1]))

Comment: @AivanF. Добавил для многозначных. Пардоньте за задержку.